# Compact manifold and eigenvalues

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ be a compact manifold and $f : X \to X$ a smooth map.

> Show that $\{x \in X | f(x) =x,\ 1 \text{ is not an eigenvalue of }df_x : T_xX \to T_xX\}$ is a finite set.

If $1$ isn't an eigenvalue then $\det(df_x - I)\neq 0$ which is an open set condition. So I guess we can do a "open cover has finite subcover" argument.
But I didn't really use $f(x)=x$ condition.

Comment: You did, implicitly. If $f(x)\ne x$, then it does not even make sense to talk of an eigenvalue of $df_x$, because it is a map of $T_x M$ to $T_{f(x)}M$ and these are different vector spaces. I have to say that this had me confused as well.

Comment: This is an interesting exercise. Thanks for posing this question. Ever wondered why we care a lot about the eigenvalues of the Hessian but we never mention the eigenvalues of the Jacobian matrix? This is why. They only make geometric sense at fixed points.

Comment: For the longest time, I had the misconception that since all the tangent spaces are ≈ $R^n$ we can define determinant. I was told recently by a fellow student that since the isomorphism isn't canonical, determinant isn't well defined.

Comment: Exactly. Unless you are at a fixed point.

Answer (score 3):

This is false. Take the function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = x + e^{-1/x^2} x^2 \sin(1/x)$. The function is chosen to have oscillating behavior near zero, while dampening it so that the resulting function is smooth. While this is a non-compact manifold, all that really matters here is the behavior near 0, so you can replace this with a function from the circle to itself which agrees with this function near a point on the circle.

There are fixed points at all $x = 1/k\pi$ for all integers $k$. Now take a derivative. For nonzero $x$ we get $$1 + \frac 2x e^{-1/x^2} \sin(1/x) + 2 e^{-1/x^2} x \sin(1/x) - \frac 1x e^{-1/x^2} \cos(1/x).$$

At $0$ the derivative (limit of the above expression) is 1.

For $x = 1/k\pi$ the derivative of the above expression evaluates to $1 - k\pi e^{-k^2 \pi^2} \cos(k\pi) \neq 1.$$

Therefore the set of fixed points so that $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $df_x$ is not closed: there are such fixed points which accumulate to 0, where 1 is an eigenvalue.

Answer (score 2):

**Caution** This proves only that the set is discrete, without proving that the set is closed, this answer is incomplete/incorrect.

Since $X$ is compact, it suffices to show that the set $S$ is discrete.

If $S$ is not discrete, there is $s_0\in S$ and a sequence $s_n\in S$ so that $s_n\neq s_0$ for all $n$ and $s_n \to s$. Taking a subsequence if necessary, assume that $s_n$ lies in a coordinates chart $(U, \phi)$ which contains $s_0$. Then

$$ \phi \circ F\circ \phi^{-1}:\phi( U)\to \mathbb R^n$$

satisfies $F(x_0) = x_0$, $F(x_n) = x_n$ for all $n$, where $x_0 = \phi (s_0)$, $x_n = \phi(s_n)$. Taking a subsequence if necessary, assume

$$ v_n=\frac{x_n - x_0}{|x_n - x_0|}\to v\in \mathbb S^{n-1}$$

The Taylor expansion at $x_0$ gives

$$F(x) = F(x_0) + \nabla  F(x_0) \cdot (x-x_0) + o(|x-x_0|),$$

putting $x = x_n$, divide the above by $|x_n - x_0|$ and use $|x_n -x_0|^{-1} o(|x_n-x_0|)\to 0$, we obtain

\begin{align} v &= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_n - x_0}{|x_n -x_0|} \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{F(x_n)-F(x_0)}{|x_n - x_0|} \\
&= \lim_{n\to \infty} \nabla F(x_0) \frac{x_n - x_0}{|x_n - x_0|} \\
&= \nabla F(x_0) v.
\end{align}

Thus $\nabla F(x_0)$ has $1$ as an eigenvalue, which is a contradiction to $s_0\in S$. Thus $S$ is a discrete set.

Comment: You need to prove that $S$ is closed. If $s_n\to s_0$ then $s_0$ is a fixed point but it's not clear that $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $d_{s_0}f$ (at least it isn't to me.)

Comment: @OlivierBégassat Thanks for pointing that out, I definitely missed that and for now don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I believe that since f(x)=x and det=0 are both closed conditions, it should be a closed set

Comment: The correct hypothesis should be that every fixed point is Lefschetz (i.e., does not have $1$ as an eigenvalue of $df_p$).